Multi-variate Picard-Lindelöf? Convergence of analytic PDEs (w/ commutative partial derivatives & value at a base point)
I am looking for a theorem to give existence and uniqueness of solutions to PDEs of the following form.

Find an analytic $u : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ satisfying the equations $\partial_{x_i}u = F_i(x,u)$, where we may assume that the $F_i$ are analytic and satisfy the commutativity conditions $\partial_{x_j}F_i(x,u) = \partial_{x_i}F_j(x,u)$.  Only a single initial value point is given, $u(0) = y_0$.

The above problem was constructed in order to give a unique multi-variate formal power series as its solution.  The commutativity conditions are necessary to ensure that the definition of that series is free of contradiction.  Under suitable Lipschitz continuity conditions on the $F_i$, I would naively assume that this power-series solution has non-zero radius of convergence and is unique.  However, I am having trouble finding an existence and uniqueness theorem which this trivially reduces to.  (e.g. Cauchy-Kovalevskaya assumes an IVP along an entire hyperplane and does not mention the commutativity conditions given)

One of the proofs of the Frobenius theorem (for which you need to update the integrability condtion, as in the answer by Pedro) involves integrating each of the equations as an ODE along a coordinate axis in some order (each step gives the initial data for the next step). When the $F_i$ are analytic, Cauchy-Kovalevskaya guarantees that the solution is analytic. These more elementary steps are basically hidden in the invocation of the Cartan-Kähler theorem also mentioned by Pedro.

True, this is actually simpler. The proof of the Frobenius theorem Igor refers to rewrites the PDE system as a prescription for an involutive vector sub-bundle of the tangent bundle (involutivity is encoded in the integrability conditions and amounts to saying that the Lie bracket of any two vector fields tangent to this sub-bundle remain so) and finds a local trivialization of this sub-bundle by commuting vector fields, which therefore have commuting flows (solving the ODE's Igor refers to) yielding the adapted coordinate charts of the integral manifold through the given initial condition.

I don't think your integrability conditions are quite correct. By the chain rule and the PDE system $\partial_{x_i}u=F_i(x,u)$, they should read $$\partial_{x_j}F_i(x,u)+\langle F_j(x,u),\nabla_u\rangle F_i(x,u)=\partial_{x_i}F_j(x,u)+\langle F_i(x,u),\nabla_u\rangle F_j(x,u)\ .$$ Once this is done, the fact that a unique $C^1$ solution $u$ exists in a neighborhood of $0$ with a given initial condition $u(0)=y_0$ is nothing more than the Frobenius theorem (which, on its turn, requires the $F_j$'s to be only $C^1$ as well). Notice that the above integrability conditions are necessary for the solution $u$ to exist, so they absolutely must have the above form.
To get the analyticity of $u$ from the analyticity of $F_j$, one notices that under the latter hypothesis the Frobenius theorem (reformulated in the language of differential ideals of differential forms or, more generally, in the language of jet bundles) becomes a special case of the Cartan-Kähler theorem, which then ensures the desired property of $u$. The Cartan-Kähler theorem generalizes the Frobenius theorem in the sense that it applies to PDE systems such that in order to get all integrability conditions one needs only to differentiate a finite number of times the PDE system together with all integrability conditions arising after differentiating less times. Frobenius is the case when differentiating a (first-order) PDE system such as the given one more than once in the above fashion yields no new integrability conditions.
If one only needs to differentiate a given PDE system a finite number of times in the fashion described in the previous paragraph to get all integrability conditions, that makes the PDE system obtained from the original one by including all integrability conditions what is called an involutive PDE system (which is the same as saying that differentiating this new system yields no new integrability conditions), so the Cartan-Kähler theorem is nothing more than an existence and uniqueness theorem for (analytic) solutions of (analytic) involutive PDE systems. In order for no integrability conditions to arise at all from the original PDE system, the latter needs to be in the Cauchy-Kovalevskaya normal form, so in this case the Cartan-Kähler theorem becomes the Cauchy-Kovalevskaya theorem. More generally, the Cartan-Kähler theorem relies on the Cauchy-Kovalevskaya theorem in its proof, just like the Frobenius theorem relies on the Picard-Lindelöf theorem for existence and uniqueness of solutions of ODE's. Notice, however, that the solution $u$ provided by the Cartan-Kähler theorem with the initial condition $u(0)=y_0$ is only guaranteed to exist in an open neighborhood of $0$, as it happens with the Frobenius theorem.

Sorry for the slowness to accept the answer.  I got side tracked with a lot of things, but this seems correct.  Thanks!  I re-derived these from the Lie-derivative formulation to confirm.
